# $.css('transition','value') doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to apply css3 transition on the fly, but jquery doesn't do anything.

code

```
var test = $("#test");
test.css("transition","all 500ms");
```

i also tried

```
var delay = "500ms";

test.css({
    'transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-moz-transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-webkit-transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-o-transition': 'all ' + delay
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

**Updated:**

"jquery doesn't do anything" literally means that it doesn't apply style to the element. I don't mean that the element doesn't move.

**Correction:**

it actually works...it was my browser.

Comment: have you checked on the debugger if those styles are actually applied? not just but looking at it?

Comment: @Joseph // Yes..i checked it. jquery didn't apply any styles..i'm trying to find out why

Comment: Use .addClass to add a css class that defines your transition: works in one line of code. See my answer below.

Comment: @frenchie // the reason I'm using inline style is that I like to set delay variable on the fly.

Comment: @Moon: You can create several css classes with different speeds. SlowCustomTransition, MediumCustomTransition and FastCustomTransition. And then you still only have one line of javascript (the .addClass line) and you pass in the name of the class as the speed parameter. Would work with only one line in. How many different kinds of transition speeds does it take to give the user a good headache?

Comment: @frenchie // i can simply make a function with the answer provided below and stop worrying about making css classes. Why would I create bunch of css classes when I can simply use a single function? users would not know if I use a js function or css classes.

Comment: Why would you create a bunch of css classes anyway? It's like jquery's slow/medium/fast parameters: they have 3. Of course, they also allow for full customization but in most cases, you only need slow/medium/fast. My style is that anytime I can find a one-liner solution, it's probably better than something that's perhaps only technically better. You're deciding between having a function and having just a statement, and both work.

Comment: @frenchie // Thank you for your suggestion, but you're talking about something that I didn't ask. My question is related to a function, not a css class. I believe we all know that we can simply use css. I'm not exactly sure why you down voted other answers as well. Those answers belong to this question. I think you're missing the point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var delay = "500ms",
    test  = $("#test");

test.css({
    'transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-moz-transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-webkit-transition': 'all ' + delay,
    '-o-transition': 'all ' + delay
}).on('click', function () {
    $(this).css({ left : '+=100' });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YwfjF/

You can see that it works, but you have to change a property for it to be animated.

Here is a great reference for CSS3 transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition (notice the links at the bottom that describe the different parts of the transition declaration).

Comment: Jasper // weird...it doesn't work on my chrome;; but it works on my ff. Must be my browser.

Comment: @Moon Since you're diving into the world of experimental features here, I recommend reading about the common pitfalls of using vender prefixes: http://paulirish.com/2012/vendor-prefixes-are-not-developer-friendly/

Comment: An explanation of the down-vote would be appreciated. I always like to know how to improve my code.

Comment: I didn't down vote. I actually voted up. Not sure what happened. It seems like my vote for jfriend00 is gone as well.

Comment: Yes, I down voted the answer because I think it's too verbose: why so many lines of javascript when it can be done in one line?? And I'm pretty sure that in terms of performance, having just .addClass() is faster than having an event listener triggering a change in css. As for the delay parameter, this is a typical programmer's approach looking to corner all possibilities but in reality, you might only need 2 or 3 different animation speeds: just build 2-3 css classes (see note above) with different delays and pass the name of the css class you want as the speed parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand how CSS3 transitions work.  The CSS3 transition settings control how property changes to an object are handled and whether they take immediate effect or whether they trigger a transition so it transtions to the new value over time.

You must have an actual property change to have a transition.  Setting the transition value itself does not trigger a transition - it just sets up the rules for when a transition will occur in the future.

In your example, you'd have to actually change some value to see a change.  For example:

```
test.css("height", "100px");
```

Since you have `transition: all`, that would trigger a transition from the current height value to the new height value.

For example, here's a CSS3 transition I created for another question a couple days ago: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/P2H4Z/.

In that example, there is this CSS relevant to the transition:

```
.element
{
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    padding: 0 10px;

    -moz-transition: left 1s; 
    -webkit-transition: left 1s; 
    -o-transition: left 1s; 
    -ms-transition: left 1s; 
     transition: left 1s; 
}


.element.seen {
    left: 0;
}
```

This sets the stage for a transition of the `left` property.  It does not trigger a transition.  The transition can be triggered by actually making a change to the `left` property on the item with `class="element"`.  That change to the `left` value can be done by:

1. Adding a class to the item or a parent item which causes a different `left` value to take effect from the CSS rules.
2. Triggering a pseudo class to take effect (like `:hover`)
3. Programmatically changing the value of `.left` with javascript.

In this particular example, the `seen` class is added to the object which causes the left value to change from `-100%` to `0`.  Because `transition left 1s` is defined, the browser will transition from the current `-100%` value to the new `0` value over a duration of 1s and thus the object will slide into place.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: define a css class for transitions:

```
.CustomTransitionClass{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;}
```

Step 2: add the class:

```
 $("#test").addClass('CustomTransitionClass');
```

Comment: Or you can even apply the `width` via a class then you're removing the CSS code from the JS code (which is usually helpful for code maintenance). I do this when I run CSS3 animations, basically queuing different classes at different times to create a multi-step animation.

Comment: Yes, I actually use it like this to show the user something happened on a block on the page: $('#MyDiv').addClass('BrightRedBackGround CustomTransition'); $('#MyDiv').removeClass('BrightRedBackGround');

Comment: frenchie you just didn't answer to the question. I don't think if someone ask a question the answer should be another. I agree that you can obtain the same effect with a css class, but if you want full customization, and you want be able to reuse it as a plugin, your answer is just wrong...you are hard coding instead of coding. In my opinion you write code to be reused, otherwise why you should bother at all in writing something...just find what other people wrote for you!!!

Comment: @Dinuz: actually, this does exactly what the OP asked for, with just one line of JS code. He's looking to add a CSS3 transition on the fly